# How to write a query in Core Data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have used core data in my apps. My application works fine in online and offline mode . I have doubt about, how to write a query in Core data(Similar SQLite). I wrote a query and used in SQLite. But I want to know about, how to write a query(select, insert, update, etc,.) using core data.

Please guide me and give me some useful links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read though [Apple's tutorial on Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html). It goes through the process of making a very simple app that used Core Data. For more complicated queries you will want to make a [predicate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html) to restrict the returned values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot write SQL like query (select, insert, update...), rather you have to use NSPredicate objects. Which support such type of operation in its own way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use predicate while fetching data . For more info ,  [visit here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html)